# Getting data from more than 2 mysql tables with join.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

Here is my tables structure.

```
Table1  // it has 4 colums,that saves all the question posted by user

id|question|answer|postby|

Table2  //it has 2 colums, that saves all the signed up users

id|username|email|

Table3 //it saves that which question is read by which user.

id|reader_id|question_id|
```

NOTE:reader_id is the id of table 2.

Problem: We need to find out those questions that are not being read by a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 where id not in (
    select question_id from table3 where reader_id = [particular user id]
)
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply Loic we also need email from Table2 because Table2 saves the info of that persons who posted the question and reading.

Comment: The best way is then to make a second request :

`select email from table2 where id = [particular user id]`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT question FROM table1 where id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM table3 where reader_id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 where username='XXXX'))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT t3.* 
   FROM 
   table2 t2
   JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.reader_id=t2.id
   WHERE t3.reader_id=SOME USER)t ON t.question_id=t1.id
WHERE t3.id IS NULL;
```